Bibtex DOI only bilbography
For a document with very little space I need bibliography items to only take 1 line each, always. I'd like to have a blilbiography that of format
J. Doe *et al*, DOI:123.345.6789, 2024

As full names and titles etc take too much space. I don't seem to be able to do this with any existing bilbiography style, nor have I found a way to edit it to have this.

You may custom the doi+eprint+url macro.
For example, something like this:
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    \ifbibliography%
        {\iftoggle{bbx:doi}
            {\printfield{doi}}
            {}%
        \newunit\newblock
        \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
            {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
            {}%
        \newunit\newblock
        \iftoggle{bbx:url}
            {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
            {}}%
        {}}

Just write it in the preamble.
You can see that I imposed to hide from citations not only doi fields, but also url fields and eprint fields.
